# How to re-add the security question in Gmail?

Tags: google-account, security

As we all might know that today is "Safe Internet Day". So Google is reminding us for the security check-up. I tried it. And I saw that I could remove my security question. I did it with the belief that I will add a better question (I forgot the answer of the earlier question anyway).

But when I tried it then I found that there is no option to add a new security question. I believe that the security question is necessary. Here is a picture how Recovery options looks like for me.

[image] There should be something with the name called 'Security Question' below 'Recovery phone'. Is there a way by which I can add that question? When I removed it I even got a mail from Google. By clicking that link I was directly forwarded to 'My last device activity', which is definitely not helpful in adding the question again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Google found that security questions were not really secure at all as most of the answers can be found with a simple Google search.  For example Sarah Palin had her Yahoo! account hacked because someone simply Googled her birthday, ZIP code and where she met her spouse.

Google has completely removed support for security questions and one only had the ability to remove already existing ones. **There is no way to add your security question back in**.
Perhaps you should consider enabling 2 - step verification, enabling this feature will make Google send a single-use code to your phone which you will have to enter as a second password. In this way even if someone manages to acquire your password, they will also need your phone to access your Google account.

Please also read: [How to create a secure password.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32040?hl=en)

Comment: if you still have one,  trying to **edit it** will actually ***DELETE IT*** with no notice and no way to undo it - it was ***NOT*** clear at all that Google had removed the security questions... (at least in late 2015) unless you researched it beforehand - a real dick move by Google, tricking people just trying to update their security info.

Comment: Can you please suggest anything else for security? I don't have any mobile phone now.

Comment: Having a mixture of complex passwords for all your sites is probably a good idea, since most people may have trouble remembering these it is worthwhile using something like LastPass or DashLane to keep them all secure in one program. Apart from that there is relatively little you can do to keep your Google account secure. It is incredibly difficult to hack someones Google account unless there password is something obvious like their name, and although there are a lot of media scares relatively few people have ever had their accounts hacked.

Comment: @SleepingGod: Sorry, there is a lot you can do to make your account more secure: add a valid phone number for a recovery phone number, a valid email address for a recovery email address, use a hard-to-guess password that's not used anywhere else, and use two-factor authentication. Accounts getting hacked *does* happen, and if you're not famous like Sarah Palin, you might not get any help at all from Google employees.

Comment: So Google punishes us users who actually use un-guessable security questions (such as my best friend when I was a kid was "T-har-qrug-tlem-zmen") and forces us to divulge real personal info instead.